# Injection of blank characters into a variable

Tags: c#, asp.net, string

```
string blankChar = "               "; /15 characters
```

**Is there a nicer way to do this?**

Like: `blankChar[15] = " ";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes there are many ways, but this `string s = new string(' ', 15);` looks simple.